# Javascript/JQuery: focus the popup window if already opened but not to reload it

Tags: javascript, jquery

Have the following code to open and focus the window popup, unless it hasn't opened yet. It works fine,

But the problem is after focus to the previous opened popup window, can't prevent reloading it and it makes loss of the data on it.

So how can prevent the existing window not to reload to retain the existing data when the link is clicked again?

```
window.open(url,"searchPatron","height=600,width=1000, status=yes,toolbar=no,menubar=no,location=no").focus();
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it fits your needs:

### DEMO

```
window['windows'] = {};
var url = "//testit.com";
$('button').click(function () {
    var popup =  window['windows'][url]? window['windows'][url]:
    window['windows'][url] = window.open(url, "searchPatron", "height=600,width=1000, status=yes,toolbar=no,menubar=no,location=no");
    popup.focus();
});
```

Comment: Thanks let me check it

Comment: Thanks for your help. When I check it, that way works fine in FF but not in IE8 browser. In IE, it just highlight the existing popup in menu, but can't focus it. Can you help me more, pls?

Comment: Not sure how IE8 handles it. Maybe this is just not possible in IE8. Now just to be sure, i'd test it like this: `setTimeout(function(){popup.focus();},1000);` See if that makes any difference. EDIT: just tested in IE8 (win7) and works for me.

Comment: Still having problem in my IE8 (win7) with `setTimeout(function(){popup.focus();},1000);`. I will check with other IE9 and IE10 version too.
Anyway thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: The fiddle seems to have been deleted...?